# Do FP operations give EXACTLY the same result on various x86 CPUs?

Tags: x86, floating-accuracy

Do different x86 CPUs (with build-in FPUs and reasonably recent, say launched this millenium) produce *exactly* the same result for their Floating Point primitives, assuming the same instruction is available on the CPUs being compared, same input and same operating parameters such as rounding mode? I'm not interested in differences in timing, nor in the [Pentium FDIV bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FDIV_bug) (which does not qualify only because that incident is ancient).

I guess the answer is yes for addition, subtraction, negation, and round-to-integer, since these have precise definitions, and I can hardly imagine what a divergence in implementations could be (short perhaps of a bug in the detection of overflow/underflow, but that would be a disaster in some applications, so I imagine this would have been caught and fixed long ago).

Multiplication seems more likely to have diverging implementations: determining the (say) nearest representable Double-Precision Float-Point Number (64 bits, including 52+1 of mantissa) of the product of two DPFPN sometime requires computing the product of their mantissa to (about) 104-bit accuracy, which, for the few LSBits, is arguably a waste of effort. I wonder if this is even attempted, and done correctly. Or perhaps IEEE-754, or some de-facto standard, prescribes something?

Division seems even more delicate.

And, short of a common design, I doubt all implementations of the much more complex things (trig functions, logs..) could be exactly in sync, given the variety of mathematical methods that can be used.

I'm asking that out of a combination of pure nosiness; willingness to improve [that answer of mine](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2716/555); and desire for a method to (sometime) allow a program running in a VM to detect a mismatch between the CPU that pretends to be running, and the real one.

Comment: While the question is very interesting (and I'd like to see an answer), it seems unlikely that you could use this to detect virtualization. Most VMs I run (VMWare and KVM primarily) have the physical CPU correctly reported, so chipset oddities wouldn't cause a mismatch in that case.

Comment: Optimized code generation is a far bigger thing to worry about.  The FPU is *very* difficult to optimize for in a consistent way.  Big reason compilers have been moving to SSE2.

Comment: I disagree with the close comments.  Although the motivation for the question may be non-constructive, the actual question is quite valid, and can be "supported by facts, references, or specific expertise."

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On assembly level basic floating-point instructions (add, subtract, multiply, divide, square root, FMA, round) always produce the same result, as described by IEEE754 standard. There are two kinds of instructions which may produce different results on different architectures: complex FPU instructions for computing transcendental operations (FSIN, FCOS, F2XM1, and alike), and approximate SSE instructions (RCPSS/RCPPS for computing approximate reciprocal, and RSQRTSS, RSQRTPS for computing approximate reciprocal square root). Transcendental x87 FPU operations are implemented in microcode, and AFAIK all Intel and AMD CPUs except AMD K5 use the same microcode, so you can't use it for detection. It might be helpful only for detection of VIA, Cyrix, Transmeta, and other old CPUs, but those are too rare to consider. Approximate SSE instructions are implemented differently on Intel and AMD, and AFAIK there is some difference in implementation on old (pre-K8) and newer AMD CPUs. You could use that difference to detect AMD CPU pretending to be Intel and vice versa, but that is a limited use-case.

Comment: I have done some randomized experiments which are consistent with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13102431/903600) and [that other](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13102625/903600) answer. I fed pseudo-random bits (converted to 80-bit long double using a C union) to `/`, `sqrtl`, `sinl` (implemented as x87 instructions), and hashed the results (converted back to bits), 1e6 times. The only difference I located was with `sinl`, which gave different hashes between Intel and AMD (but consistent between PIII and Core i7, as well as Athlon XP and Althlon 5050e).

Comment: @fgrieu: `/` and `sqrtl` are IEEE-754 "basic" operations, along with + - and *, and thus required to produce "correctly rounded" results on conforming implementations.  i.e. rounding error <= 0.5ulp, so there's no wiggle room in the result.  The result is determined by the inputs down to the last bit of the mantissa aka significand.

Comment: I confirm this information. Recently I came across the fact that the rcpss instruction works differently on different AMD processors. Because of this, the optimality of the algorithm may be violated, I will probably have to abandon this instruction.

Comment: Re "Transcendental x87 FPU operations are implemented in microcode, and AFAIK all Intel and AMD CPUs except AMD K5 use the same microcode" From first hand knowledge (I worked on the FPU side of AMD K6, K6-2, and Athlon processors) this is definitely *not* the case. If you compare the output of the transcendental instructions between AMD and Intel processors for a sufficient number of arguments, you can certainly find differences. Because both vendors maintain tight error bound for these instructionss, the percentage of mismatches will be fairly small.

Answer (score 1):

Except for extreme cases that are very well documented in errata, **ALL** IA-32 instructions behave identically across processors.

The obvious exceptions are, of course, `CPUID` and MSR accesses.

The obvious non-exceptions are the various logic, integer and floating point operations.  As [Maratyszcza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/848177/maratyszcza) wrote [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13102431/1084), many of the more complex operations are calculated by microcode.  This microcode can be very different among processors with different microarchitectures, but the result is guaranteed to be the same.  Intel, for one (I have no firsthand knowledge of other x86 developers), invests huge resources to ensure backwards compatibility between processors, even reproducing behavior that is "buggy" (which changes the bugs into the new spec).

Where the architecture behaves differently, such as with VMX (Virtualization) and SMM (System Management), the control structures include a revision ID.  All processors that use the same revision ID are guaranteed to behave the same way with regard to these architectures.

To answer the original question, FP operations, be they x87, SSE or AVX, give the same result on all processors, according to [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).