# Strange float to int conversion with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c, visual-studio, floating-point, int

Let us say I have

```
float val = 99999.9;
```

When I do this:

```
int val2 = val*100;
```

`val2` is equal to 9999989 in Visual Studio 2010.

However, if I do the same with other compilers (like GCC for example), the result would be `val2 = 9999990`.

How to explain such a difference ?

Comment: Hint 1: `float` is **floating** point and can't represent every real number exactly.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken. Hint 2: casting to `int` always rounds down.

Comment: It looks like here int does not round down val2, because val2 is 9999989 in Visual Studio.

Comment: No, it **does** round down, always (for positive values).  So this indicates that Visual Studio is representing `99999.9` by a value that is slightly **less** than `99999.9`, whereas gcc is representing it by a value that is slightly **greater**.

Comment: The point is that you need to write your code in such a way that it works correctly no matter which way the compiler chooses to represent the number.  As such, a straight cast to `int` is generally the wrong way to "convert" a floating point number to an integer.

Comment: Ok, so what do you suggest for me to have always val2 = 9999990, whatever the compiler is ?

Comment: @LudoDu31 A 'cheap' (but not always accurate) way to get a *rounding* to the nearest integer is to add 0.5 to the floating-point value before converting to an integer. Something like: `int val2 = val * 100 + 0.5;` would work in most cases.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, yes it looks working that way. However I am not sure to be able to demonstrate why

Comment: the reason is because C allows the value with a higher precision internally so on some compilers it's done in the 80-bit extended precision and some it's in SSE 32-bit single precision. There are lots of similar issues [Difference in floating point arithmetics between x86 and x64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22710272/995714), [Do FP operations give EXACTLY the same result on various x86 CPUs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13102167/995714), [acos(double) gives different result on x64 and x32 Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45734549/995714)

Comment: @phuclv: That alone does not explain it. Both the C and C++ standards require the implementation to discard excess precision in assignments and casts. So, after `float val = 99999.9;`, `val` must be some value representable in `float`. For this particular numeral, whether it is treated as an IEEE-754 binary32 or binary64 or an Intel 80-bit floating-point value, the result would be 9999990. Microsoft must be doing something other than what the standard says.

Comment: Please edit the question to provide a [mre].