# Regression output is different on different computers

Tags: r, statistics, regression, numeric, glm

We are fitting a generalized linear model to a set of data using R on Fedora 33. We are 3 people that have the exact same data set, exact same OS (Fedora 33) , exact same R version and package version. The sessionInfo() output also looks the same. This is the current function call:

```
probitModel <- glm(Y ~ a + b + c +
                     d + e + f + g,
                   control=glm.control(maxit=100), 
                   start=startingval,
                   family = binomial(link = "probit"),
                   data = thisData)
```

Something to note is that a normal "lm" fit yields the exact same result when compared. Something about "glm" yields different results on different computers by a tiny amount. Finally, the results are consistent in the sense that we all get the same result with the same data in the same computer. The problem only appears when we compare results.

We have checked:

- Same OS version.
- Same R version.
- Same package version.
- Same seed.
- All computers are 64 bit and the R install is 64 bit.
- Same sessionInfo()
- Same g++ version.

[The data file can be found here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-faU8cuCBgXX5oL-FRC3nnzQDGZdWdqa/view?usp=sharing). We just use load() to set up the data, called the function above and we get slightly different outputs when the output should be the same.

My result for sprintf("%.20f", probitModel$coefficients):

```
"-2.87521118137333120401" "-0.29134882504319664642" "0.11641651353472137753"  "-0.00811350544106945529" "0.00939647781971938295"  "0.00000000889056301580"  "-0.00000000003021053820" "0.04553200818707187070"
```

Result from the other computer:

```
"-2.87521124006409856122" "-0.29134881939721285482" "0.11641651896472486605"  "-0.00811350937056383621" "0.00939647799201156347" "0.00000000889056417264"  "-0.00000000003021022404" "0.04553201421062236243"
```

My trace output:

```
    Deviance = 67234.8 Iterations - 1
    Deviance = 67079.56 Iterations - 2
    Deviance = 67102.68 Iterations - 3
    Deviance = 67088.05 Iterations - 4
    Deviance = 67078.07 Iterations - 5
    Deviance = 67073.77 Iterations - 6
    Deviance = 67076.34 Iterations - 7
    Deviance = 67074.41 Iterations - 8
    Deviance = 67075.74 Iterations - 9
    Deviance = 67074.77 Iterations - 10
    Deviance = 67075.45 Iterations - 11
    Deviance = 67074.96 Iterations - 12
    Deviance = 67075.31 Iterations - 13
    Deviance = 67075.06 Iterations - 14
    Deviance = 67075.23 Iterations - 15
    Deviance = 67075.11 Iterations - 16
    Deviance = 67075.2 Iterations - 17
    Deviance = 67075.13 Iterations - 18
    Deviance = 67075.18 Iterations - 19
    Deviance = 67075.15 Iterations - 20
    Deviance = 67075.17 Iterations - 21
    Deviance = 67075.15 Iterations - 22
    Deviance = 67075.16 Iterations - 23
    Deviance = 67075.16 Iterations - 24
    Deviance = 67075.16 Iterations - 25
    Deviance = 67075.16 Iterations - 26
    Deviance = 67075.16 Iterations - 27
    Deviance = 67075.16 Iterations - 28
    Deviance = 67075.16 Iterations - 29
    Deviance = 67075.16 Iterations - 30
    Deviance = 67075.16 Iterations - 31
    Deviance = 67075.16 Iterations - 32
```

Other computer's trace output:

```
Deviance = 67234.8 Iterations - 1
Deviance = 67079.56 Iterations - 2
Deviance = 67102.68 Iterations - 3
Deviance = 67088.05 Iterations - 4
Deviance = 67078.07 Iterations - 5
Deviance = 67073.77 Iterations - 6
Deviance = 67076.34 Iterations - 7
Deviance = 67074.41 Iterations - 8
Deviance = 67075.74 Iterations - 9
Deviance = 67074.77 Iterations - 10
Deviance = 67075.45 Iterations - 11
Deviance = 67074.96 Iterations - 12
Deviance = 67075.31 Iterations - 13
Deviance = 67075.06 Iterations - 14
Deviance = 67075.23 Iterations - 15
Deviance = 67075.11 Iterations - 16
Deviance = 67075.2 Iterations - 17
Deviance = 67075.13 Iterations - 18
Deviance = 67075.18 Iterations - 19
Deviance = 67075.15 Iterations - 20
Deviance = 67075.17 Iterations - 21
Deviance = 67075.15 Iterations - 22
Deviance = 67075.16 Iterations - 23
Deviance = 67075.16 Iterations - 24
Deviance = 67075.16 Iterations - 25
Deviance = 67075.16 Iterations - 26
Deviance = 67075.16 Iterations - 27
Deviance = 67075.16 Iterations - 28
Deviance = 67075.16 Iterations - 29
Deviance = 67075.16 Iterations - 30
Deviance = 67075.16 Iterations - 31
Deviance = 67075.16 Iterations - 32
```

My options() output:

```
$askpass
function (prompt) 
{
    .rs.askForPassword(prompt)
}
<environment: 0x5557fac219c8>

$asksecret
function (name, title = name, prompt = paste(name, ":", sep = "")) 
{
    .rs.askForSecret(name, title, prompt)
}
<environment: 0x5557fac219c8>

$bitmapType
[1] "cairo"
   
$CBoundsCheck
[1] FALSE

$check.bounds
[1] FALSE

$citation.bibtex.max
[1] 1


$continue
[1] "+ "

$contrasts
        unordered           ordered 
"contr.treatment"      "contr.poly" 

$defaultPackages
[1] "datasets"  "utils"     "grDevices" "graphics"  "stats"     "methods"  

$demo.ask
[1] "default"

$deparse.cutoff
[1] 60

$device
[1] "RStudioGD"

$device.ask.default
[1] FALSE

$digits
[1] 7

$download.file.method
[1] "libcurl"

$dvipscmd
[1] "dvips"

$echo
[1] TRUE

$editor
[1] "/usr/bin/nano"

$encoding
[1] "native.enc"

$example.ask
[1] "default"

$expressions
[1] 5000

$ggvis.renderer
[1] "svg"

$help_type
[1] "html"

$help.search.types
[1] "vignette" "demo"     "help"    

$help.try.all.packages
[1] FALSE

$HTTPUserAgent
[1] "RStudio Desktop (1.4.1106); R (4.0.4 x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu x86_64 linux-gnu)"

$internet.info
[1] 2

$keep.parse.data
[1] TRUE

$keep.parse.data.pkgs
[1] FALSE

$keep.source
[1] TRUE

$keep.source.pkgs
[1] FALSE

$locatorBell
[1] TRUE

$mailer
[1] "mailto"

$matprod
[1] "default"

$max.print
[1] 1000

$menu.graphics
[1] FALSE

$na.action
[1] "na.omit"

$nwarnings
[1] 50

$OutDec
[1] "."

$papersize
[1] "letter"

$PCRE_limit_recursion
[1] NA

$PCRE_study
[1] FALSE

$PCRE_use_JIT
[1] TRUE

$pdfviewer
[1] "/usr/bin/xdg-open"

$pkgType
[1] "source"

$profvis.keep_output
[1] TRUE

$profvis.print
function (x) 
{
    .rs.profilePrint(x)
}
<environment: 0x5557f91aadb0>

$profvis.prof_extension
[1] ".Rprof"


$prompt
[1] "> "

$repos
                       CRAN 
"https://cran.rstudio.com/" 
attr(,"RStudio")
[1] TRUE

$restart
function (afterRestartCommand = "") 
{
    .rs.restartR(afterRestartCommand)
}
<environment: 0x5557fac219c8>

$reticulate.initialized
function () 
{
    options(reticulate.initialized = NULL)
    .rs.reticulate.onPythonInitialized()
    .rs.reticulate.enqueueClientEvent(.rs.reticulateEvents$PYTHON_INITIALIZED, 
        list())
    .Call("rs_reticulateInitialized", PACKAGE = "(embedding)")
}
<environment: 0x5557f8bbf4d0>

$reticulate.repl.hook
function (buffer, contents, trimmed) 
{
    .rs.reticulate.replHook(buffer, contents, trimmed)
}
<environment: 0x5557f8bbf4d0>

$reticulate.repl.initialize
function () 
{
    .rs.reticulate.replInitialize()
}
<environment: 0x5557f8bbf4d0>

$reticulate.repl.teardown
function () 
{
    .rs.reticulate.replTeardown()
}
<environment: 0x5557f8bbf4d0>

$rl_word_breaks
[1] " \t\n\"\\'`><=%;,|&{()}"

$rsconnect.check.certificate
[1] TRUE

$rstudio.notebook.executing
[1] FALSE

$RStudioGD.antialias
[1] "default"

$RStudioGD.backend
[1] "default"

$scipen
[1] 0

$shiny.launch.browser
function (url) 
{
    invisible(.Call("rs_shinyviewer", url, getwd(), "window", 
        NULL, PACKAGE = "(embedding)"))
}
<environment: base>
attr(,"shinyViewerType")
[1] "window"

$shinygadgets.showdialog
function (caption, url, width = NULL, height = NULL) 
{
    if (!is.character(caption) || (length(caption) != 1)) 
        stop("caption must be a single element character vector.", 
            call. = FALSE)
    if (!is.character(url) || (length(url) != 1)) 
        stop("url must be a single element character vector.", 
            call. = FALSE)
    if (is.null(width)) 
        width <- 600
    if (is.null(height)) 
        height <- 600
    if (!is.numeric(width) || (length(width) != 1)) 
        stop("width must be a single element numeric vector.", 
            call. = FALSE)
    if (!is.numeric(height) || (length(height) != 1)) 
        stop("height must be a single element numeric vector.", 
            call. = FALSE)
    invisible(.Call("rs_showShinyGadgetDialog", caption, url, 
        width, height, PACKAGE = "(embedding)"))
}
<environment: 0x5557fac219c8>

$show.coef.Pvalues
[1] TRUE

$show.error.messages
[1] TRUE

$show.signif.stars
[1] TRUE

$str
$str$strict.width
[1] "no"

$str$digits.d
[1] 3

$str$vec.len
[1] 4

$str$list.len
[1] 99

$str$deparse.lines
NULL

$str$drop.deparse.attr
[1] TRUE

$str$formatNum
function (x, ...) 
format(x, trim = TRUE, drop0trailing = TRUE, ...)
<environment: 0x5557f9ae0330>


$str.dendrogram.last
[1] "`"

$stringsAsFactors
[1] FALSE

$terminal.manager
$terminal.manager$terminalActivate
function (id = NULL, show = TRUE) 
{
    if (!is.null(id) && (!is.character(id) || (length(id) != 
        1))) 
        stop("'id' must be NULL or a character vector of length one")
    if (!is.logical(show)) 
        stop("'show' must be TRUE or FALSE")
    .Call("rs_terminalActivate", id, show)
    invisible(NULL)
}

$terminal.manager$terminalCreate
function (caption = NULL, show = TRUE, shellType = NULL) 
{
    if (!is.null(caption) && (!is.character(caption) || (length(caption) != 
        1))) 
        stop("'caption' must be NULL or a character vector of length one")
    if (is.null(show) || !is.logical(show)) 
        stop("'show' must be a logical vector")
    if (!is.null(shellType) && (!is.character(shellType) || (length(shellType) != 
        1))) 
        stop("'shellType' must be NULL or a character vector of length one")
    validShellType = TRUE
    if (!is.null(shellType)) {
        validShellType <- tolower(shellType) %in% c("default", 
            "win-cmd", "win-ps", "win-git-bash", "win-wsl-bash", 
            "ps-core", "custom")
    }
    if (!validShellType) 
        stop("'shellType' must be NULL, or one of 'default', 'win-cmd', 'win-ps', 'win-git-bash', 'win-wsl-bash', 'ps-core', 'bash', 'zsh', or 'custom'.")
    .Call("rs_terminalCreate", caption, show, shellType)
}

$terminal.manager$terminalClear
function (id) 
{
    if (is.null(id) || !is.character(id) || length(id) != 1) 
        stop("'id' must be a character vector of length one")
    .Call("rs_terminalClear", id)
    invisible(NULL)
}

$terminal.manager$terminalList
function () 
{
    .Call("rs_terminalList")
}

$terminal.manager$terminalContext
function (id) 
{
    if (is.null(id) || !is.character(id) || (length(id) != 1)) 
        stop("'id' must be a single element character vector")
    .Call("rs_terminalContext", id)
}

$terminal.manager$terminalBuffer
function (id, stripAnsi = TRUE) 
{
    if (is.null(id) || !is.character(id) || (length(id) != 1)) 
        stop("'id' must be a single element character vector")
    if (is.null(stripAnsi) || !is.logical(stripAnsi)) 
        stop("'stripAnsi' must be a logical vector")
    .Call("rs_terminalBuffer", id, stripAnsi)
}

$terminal.manager$terminalVisible
function () 
{
    .Call("rs_terminalVisible")
}

$terminal.manager$terminalBusy
function (id) 
{
    if (is.null(id) || !is.character(id)) 
        stop("'id' must be a character vector")
    .Call("rs_terminalBusy", id)
}

$terminal.manager$terminalRunning
function (id) 
{
    if (is.null(id) || !is.character(id)) 
        stop("'id' must be a character vector")
    .Call("rs_terminalRunning", id)
}

$terminal.manager$terminalKill
function (id) 
{
    if (is.null(id) || !is.character(id)) 
        stop("'id' must be a character vector")
    .Call("rs_terminalKill", id)
    invisible(NULL)
}

$terminal.manager$terminalSend
function (id, text) 
{
    if (!is.character(text)) 
        stop("'text' should be a character vector", call. = FALSE)
    if (is.null(id) || !is.character(id) || length(id) != 1) 
        stop("'id' must be a character vector of length one")
    .Call("rs_terminalSend", id, text)
    invisible(NULL)
}

$terminal.manager$terminalExecute
function (command, workingDir = NULL, env = character(), show = TRUE) 
{
    if (is.null(command) || !is.character(command) || (length(command) != 
        1)) 
        stop("'command' must be a single element character vector")
    if (!is.null(workingDir) && (!is.character(workingDir) || 
        (length(workingDir) != 1))) 
        stop("'workingDir' must be a single element character vector")
    if (!is.null(env) && !is.character(env)) 
        stop("'env' must be a character vector")
    if (is.null(show) || !is.logical(show)) 
        stop("'show' must be a logical vector")
    .Call("rs_terminalExecute", command, workingDir, env, show, 
        PACKAGE = "(embedding)")
}


$texi2dvi
[1] "/usr/bin/texi2dvi"

$timeout
[1] 60

$ts.eps
[1] 1e-05

$ts.S.compat
[1] FALSE

$unzip
[1] "/usr/bin/unzip"

$useFancyQuotes
[1] TRUE

$verbose
[1] FALSE

$viewer
function (url, height = NULL) 
{
    if (!is.character(url) || (length(url) != 1)) 
        stop("url must be a single element character vector.", 
            call. = FALSE)
    if (identical(height, "maximize")) 
        height <- -1
    if (!is.null(height) && (!is.numeric(height) || (length(height) != 
        1))) 
        stop("height must be a single element numeric vector or 'maximize'.", 
            call. = FALSE)
    invisible(.Call("rs_viewer", url, height, PACKAGE = "(embedding)"))
}
<environment: 0x5557fac219c8>

$warn
[1] 0

$warning.length
[1] 1000

$width
[1] 121
```

Second computer's options() output:

```
$add.smooth
[1] TRUE

$askpass
function (prompt) 
{
    .Call("rs_askForPassword", prompt)
}
<environment: 0x55ca5c0b0978>

$asksecret
function (name, title = name, prompt = paste(name, ":", sep = "")) 
{
    result <- .Call("rs_askForSecret", name, title, prompt, .rs.isPackageInstalled("keyring"), 
        .rs.hasSecret(name))
    if (is.null(result)) 
        stop("Ask for secret operation was cancelled.")
    result
}
<environment: 0x55ca5c0b0978>

$bitmapType
[1] "cairo"

$browser
function (url) 
{
    .Call("rs_browseURL", url)
}
<environment: 0x55ca5ca2c200>

$browserNLdisabled
[1] FALSE

$buildtools.check
function (action) 
{
    if (identical(.Platform$pkgType, "mac.binary.mavericks")) {
        .Call("rs_canBuildCpp")
    }
    else {
        if (!.Call("rs_canBuildCpp")) {
            .rs.installBuildTools(action)
            FALSE
        }
        else {
            TRUE
        }
    }
}
<environment: 0x55ca5c0b0978>

$buildtools.with
function (code) 
{
    .rs.addRToolsToPath()
    on.exit(.rs.restorePreviousPath(), add = TRUE)
    force(code)
}
<environment: 0x55ca5c0b0978>

$CBoundsCheck
[1] FALSE

$check.bounds
[1] FALSE

$citation.bibtex.max
[1] 1

$connectionObserver
$connectionObserver$connectionOpened
function (type, host, displayName, icon = NULL, connectCode, 
    disconnect, listObjectTypes, listObjects, listColumns, previewObject, 
    connectionObject, actions = NULL) 
{
    if (!inherits(listObjectTypes, "function")) {
        stop("listObjectTypes must be a function returning a list of object types", 
            call. = FALSE)
    }
    promote <- function(name, l) {
        if (length(l) == 0) 
            return(list())
        if (is.null(l$contains)) {
            return(list(list(name = name, icon = l$icon, contains = "data")))
        }
        else {
            return(unlist(append(list(list(list(name = name, 
                icon = l$icon, contains = names(l$contains)))), 
                lapply(names(l$contains), function(name) {
                  promote(name, l$contains[[name]])
                })), recursive = FALSE))
        }
        return(list())
    }
    objectTree <- listObjectTypes()
    objectTypes <- lapply(names(objectTree), function(name) {
        promote(name, objectTree[[name]])
    })[[1]]
    connection <- list(type = type, host = host, displayName = displayName, 
        icon = icon, connectCode = connectCode, disconnect = disconnect, 
        objectTypes = objectTypes, listObjects = listObjects, 
        listColumns = listColumns, previewObject = previewObject, 
        actions = actions, connectionObject = connectionObject)
    class(connection) <- "rstudioConnection"
    .rs.validateConnection(connection)
    cacheKey <- paste(connection$type, connection$host, .Call("rs_generateShortUuid"), 
        sep = "_")
    assign(cacheKey, value = connection, envir = .rs.activeConnections)
    invisible(.Call("rs_connectionOpened", connection))
}
<environment: 0x55ca5d0039e0>

$connectionObserver$connectionClosed
function (type, host, ...) 
{
    .rs.validateCharacterParams(list(type = type, host = host))
    name <- .rs.findConnectionName(type, host)
    if (!is.null(name)) 
        rm(list = name, envir = .rs.activeConnections)
    invisible(.Call("rs_connectionClosed", type, host))
}
<environment: 0x55ca5d0039e0>

$connectionObserver$connectionUpdated
function (type, host, hint, ...) 
{
    .rs.validateCharacterParams(list(type = type, host = host, 
        hint = hint))
    invisible(.Call("rs_connectionUpdated", type, host, hint))
}
<environment: 0x55ca5d0039e0>


$continue
[1] "+ "

$contrasts
        unordered           ordered 
"contr.treatment"      "contr.poly" 

$defaultPackages
[1] "datasets"  "utils"     "grDevices" "graphics"  "stats"     "methods"  

$demo.ask
[1] "default"

$deparse.cutoff
[1] 60

$device
[1] "RStudioGD"

$device.ask.default
[1] FALSE

$digits
[1] 7

$download.file.method
[1] "libcurl"

$dvipscmd
[1] "dvips"

$echo
[1] TRUE

$editor
[1] "vi"

$encoding
[1] "native.enc"

$error
(function () 
{
    .rs.recordTraceback(TRUE, 5, .rs.enqueueError)
})()

$example.ask
[1] "default"

$expressions
[1] 5000

$ggvis.renderer
[1] "svg"

$help_type
[1] "html"

$help.search.types
[1] "vignette" "demo"     "help"    

$help.try.all.packages
[1] FALSE

$HTTPUserAgent
[1] "RStudio Desktop (1.3.1093); R (4.0.4 x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu x86_64 linux-gnu)"

$internet.info
[1] 2

$keep.parse.data
[1] TRUE

$keep.parse.data.pkgs
[1] FALSE

$keep.source
[1] TRUE

$keep.source.pkgs
[1] FALSE

$locatorBell
[1] TRUE

$mailer
[1] "mailto"

$matprod
[1] "default"

$max.print
[1] 1000

$menu.graphics
[1] FALSE

$na.action
[1] "na.omit"

$nwarnings
[1] 50

$OutDec
[1] "."

$page_viewer
function (url, title = "RStudio Viewer", self_contained = FALSE) 
{
    if (!is.character(url) || (length(url) != 1)) 
        stop("url must be a single element character vector.", 
            call. = FALSE)
    if (!is.character(title) || (length(title) != 1)) 
        stop("title must be a single element character vector.", 
            call. = FALSE)
    if (!is.logical(self_contained) || (length(self_contained) != 
        1)) 
        stop("self_contained must be a single element logical vector.", 
            call. = FALSE)
    invisible(.Call("rs_showPageViewer", url, title, self_contained))
}
<environment: 0x55ca5ca2c200>

$pager
function (files, header, title, delete.file) 
{
    for (i in 1:length(files)) {
        if ((i > length(header)) || !nzchar(header[[i]])) 
            fileTitle <- title
        else fileTitle <- header[[i]]
        .Call("rs_showFile", fileTitle, files[[i]], delete.file)
    }
}
<environment: 0x55ca5c0b0978>

$papersize
[1] "letter"

$PCRE_limit_recursion
[1] NA

$PCRE_study
[1] FALSE

$PCRE_use_JIT
[1] TRUE

$pdfviewer
[1] "/usr/bin/xdg-open"

$pkgType
[1] "source"

$plumber.swagger.url
function (url) 
{
    invisible(.Call("rs_plumberviewer", url, getwd(), "window", 
        PACKAGE = "(embedding)"))
}
<environment: 0x55ca5c0b0978>
attr(,"plumberViewerType")
[1] "window"

$printcmd
[1] "lpr"

$profvis.keep_output
[1] TRUE

$profvis.print
function (x) 
{
    envir <- as.environment(which(search() == "tools:rstudio"))
    eval(substitute(.rs.profilePrint(x), list(x = x)), envir = envir)
}
<environment: 0x55ca5c99fb80>

$prompt
[1] "> "

$repos
                       CRAN 
"https://cran.rstudio.com/" 
attr(,"RStudio")
[1] TRUE

$restart
function (afterRestartCommand = "") 
{
    afterRestartCommand <- paste(as.character(afterRestartCommand), 
        collapse = "\n")
    .Call("rs_restartR", afterRestartCommand, PACKAGE = "(embedding)")
}
<environment: 0x55ca5c0b0978>

$reticulate.initialized
function () 
{
    .Call("rs_reticulateInitialized", PACKAGE = "(embedding)")
}
<environment: 0x55ca5ab49dd8>

$reticulate.repl.hook
function (buffer, contents, trimmed) 
{
    if (buffer$empty()) {
        if (grepl("^[?]", trimmed)) {
            text <- substring(trimmed, 2)
            .Call("rs_showPythonHelp", text, PACKAGE = "(embedding)")
            return(TRUE)
        }
        reHelp <- "help\\((.*)\\)"
        if (grepl(reHelp, trimmed)) {
            text <- gsub(reHelp, "\\1", trimmed)
            .Call("rs_showPythonHelp", text, PACKAGE = "(embedding)")
            return(TRUE)
        }
    }
    FALSE
}
<environment: 0x55ca5c0b0978>

$reticulate.repl.initialize
function () 
{
    builtins <- reticulate::import_builtins(convert = FALSE)
    help <- builtins$help
    .rs.setVar("reticulate.help", builtins$help)
    builtins$help <- function(...) {
        dots <- list(...)
        if (length(dots) == 0) {
            message("Error: Interactive Python help not available within RStudio")
            return()
        }
        help(...)
    }
    if (requireNamespace("png", quietly = TRUE) && reticulate::py_module_available("matplotlib")) {
        matplotlib <- reticulate::import("matplotlib", convert = TRUE)
        backend <- matplotlib$get_backend()
        if (!identical(tolower(backend), "agg")) {
            sys <- reticulate::import("sys", convert = TRUE)
            if ("matplotlib.backends" %in% names(sys$modules)) 
                matplotlib$pyplot$switch_backend("agg")
            else matplotlib$use("agg", warn = FALSE, force = TRUE)
        }
        plt <- matplotlib$pyplot
        .rs.setVar("reticulate.matplotlib.show", plt$show)
        plt$show <- .rs.reticulate.matplotlib.showHook
    }
}
<environment: 0x55ca5c0b0978>

$reticulate.repl.teardown
function () 
{
    builtins <- reticulate::import_builtins(convert = FALSE)
    builtins$help <- .rs.getVar("reticulate.help")
    show <- .rs.getVar("reticulate.matplotlib.show")
    if (!is.null(show)) {
        matplotlib <- reticulate::import("matplotlib", convert = TRUE)
        plt <- matplotlib$pyplot
        plt$show <- show
    }
}
<environment: 0x55ca5c0b0978>

$rl_word_breaks
[1] " \t\n\"\\'`><=%;,|&{()}"

$rstudio.notebook.executing
[1] FALSE

$scipen
[1] 0

$shiny.launch.browser
function (url) 
{
    invisible(.Call("rs_shinyviewer", url, getwd(), "window", 
        NULL, PACKAGE = "(embedding)"))
}
<environment: 0x55ca5c0b0978>
attr(,"shinyViewerType")
[1] "window"


$str$digits.d
[1] 3

$str$vec.len
[1] 4

$str$list.len
[1] 99

$str$deparse.lines
NULL

$str$drop.deparse.attr
[1] TRUE

$str$formatNum
function (x, ...) 
format(x, trim = TRUE, drop0trailing = TRUE, ...)
<environment: 0x55ca5ba6a360>


$str.dendrogram.last
[1] "`"

$stringsAsFactors
[1] FALSE


$terminal.manager$terminalVisible
function () 
{
    .Call("rs_terminalVisible")
}
<environment: 0x55ca5c0b0978>

$terminal.manager$terminalBusy
function (id) 
{
    if (is.null(id) || !is.character(id)) 
        stop("'id' must be a character vector")
    .Call("rs_terminalBusy", id)
}
<environment: 0x55ca5c0b0978>

$terminal.manager$terminalRunning
function (id) 
{
    if (is.null(id) || !is.character(id)) 
        stop("'id' must be a character vector")
    .Call("rs_terminalRunning", id)
}
<environment: 0x55ca5c0b0978>

$terminal.manager$terminalKill
function (id) 
{
    if (is.null(id) || !is.character(id)) 
        stop("'id' must be a character vector")
    .Call("rs_terminalKill", id)
    invisible(NULL)
}
<environment: 0x55ca5c0b0978>

$terminal.manager$terminalSend
function (id, text) 
{
    if (!is.character(text)) 
        stop("'text' should be a character vector", call. = FALSE)
    if (is.null(id) || !is.character(id) || length(id) != 1) 
        stop("'id' must be a character vector of length one")
    .Call("rs_terminalSend", id, text)
    invisible(NULL)
}
<environment: 0x55ca5c0b0978>

$timeout
[1] 60

$ts.eps
[1] 1e-05
```

Comment: Different chips, different compiler versions? Really, really tiny differences can lead to differences in floating-point computations.  Can you give more context on the use-case? Figuring out the difference is academically/intellectually interesting, but you should essentially **never** be comparing exact identity of floating-point results as part of your workflow (use `all.equal()` with an appropriate tolerance rather than `identical()` or `==`)

Comment: I'll also note that there are several other reasons to suspect this is a numerically unstable fit: (1) on my system, there's a warning "glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred" (2) you have coefficients that vary over a very wide range of magnitudes, from `f`=-3e-11 to Intercept=-2.87 (max non-intercept coeff is -2.9e-1, so the range among non-intercept coeffs is almost as large)

Comment: what is `g++ --version` on each machine?

Comment: @BenBolker Well the use case is to compare results to make sure we ran our model correctly. We need to perform a certain procedure so that our models are exactly the same at the end. In order to know we did everything correctly we compare results and these small differences in the coefficients amplify some errors at the end of our procedure.

Comment: @BenBolker We usually do get "glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred" warnings. I'll update with the g++ version as soon as I can.

Comment: Same g++ version

Comment: If you don't get an answer here it might be worth asking on `r-devel@r-project.org`. I think your workflow is fundamentally problematic (what happens when you happen to have to collaborate with someone with a slightly different OS? Why are your end-of-pipe computations so unstable?) but I have to admit I'm interested in the answer. Next I would check how R was installed (from https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/fedora/ or compiled locally?), and  inspect `cat /proc/cpuinfo` ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102167/do-fp-operations-give-exactly-the-same-result-on-various-x86-cpus

Comment: You say your computers are all 64-bit. But are they really? Internally, the computations are done in 80-bit accuracy (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_extended_precision_format ). Could it be that different computers make 80-to-64 bit conversions at a different points in the chain of floating point operations. I have come across this issue when getting slightly different results from optimized and debug builds in C++.